# Angular2 : View not updating

Tags: angular, angular2-template, materialize

here is an other "View not changing" problem

I have a component that I need to update when I select a name.
But, I don't know why, I have to select 2 times the name before the model change. It's like the 1st time I choose the model is not updated.

Using angular 2 4.0.0 with materializeCSS (autocomplete coming from materialize)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ezFm.gif)

So then, I would like to directly have the button appears once I choose.

HTML Template of this part :

```
<form>
            <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
            <input id="search" type="text" name="autoComplete" materialize="autocomplete" [materializeParams]="[autocompleteInit]">
        </form>
        <div *ngIf="CVSelected.getCV()">
            <button type="button" [routerLink]="['/dashboard/cv']" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Passer à l'édition</button>
        </div>
```

AutocompleteInit:

```
autocompleteInit: any = {
    data:  {Some_data_here},
    onAutocomplete: (str: string) => {
        this.dataService.GetFromString(str).subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
            this.CVSelected.setCV(value[0]); // This makes the button appears on my template with a get
        });
        this.changement.detectChanges(); // Tried this and other functions that does the same but doesn't work
    },
};
```

Anyone ran into this problem ? If yes, some solutions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check `console.log(Zone.current.name)` inside `onAutocomplete` handler

Comment: can't find the library related to Zone.current.name. Where do I find it ?

Comment: Its zonejs. `declare let Zone: any`

Comment: `declare let Zone: any` doesn't run as I get **Modifiers cannot appear here** error. Doing only `let Zone: any` lead me to this error : https://puu.sh/wjIt1/f81ce11255.png @yurzui

Comment: Here is an example https://plnkr.co/edit/lS4Aaf3q6kKaBXugcUcN Your code should be executed inside angular zone

Comment: And looks like it's not :  the result is <root>

Comment: So that is your problem. Then try using `zone.run` like here https://plnkr.co/edit/1yKHYxxpcnztqzS7OzF0?p=info

Comment: Running ! Thank you so much :D, can you put an answer so I can close this thread? @yurzui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause in such cases is execution code outside angular zone. To solve it i would advice you to run code inside angular zone like:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

autocompleteInit: any = {
  data:  {},
  onAutocomplete: (str: string) => {
     zone.run(() => {
        this.dataService.GetFromString(str).subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value);
          this.CVSelected.setCV(value[0]); // This makes the button appears on my template with a get
        });
     });
  },
```