# View do not updated after fetch in Parse SDK and Angular 4.*

Tags: angular, parse-platform

I got a problem with custom promises in Angular 4.*
I'm using Parse SDK. 
Standard login method.

I have variable **isInvalid** in the template, I use it with *ngIf logic to display error result. The problem is that after Parse fetches his method this variable do not change in view.

```
<div *ngIf="isInvalid">Invalid username or password</div>
```

code

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import {ParseService} from '../../_global/services/parse.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.pug',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class PageLoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    public isInvalid: boolean;

    constructor(private parseService: ParseService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            login: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    private handleError(error) {
        const me = this;
        console.log('error', error);
        me.isInvalid = true;
    }

    login(loginForm: any) {
        const loginData = loginForm._value;
        const me = this;

        me.parseService.User.logIn(loginData.login, loginData.password).then(function (data) {
            console.log('User', me);
            me.isInvalid = false;
        }).catch(me.handleError);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you upload your code

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541579/angular2-view-not-updating/44543875#44543875

Comment: I saw that link but it does not work for me.